# Spring Jdbc binding java.sql.timestamp to oracle date issue

Tags: java, sql, spring, oracle, jdbc

I am currently using Spring's `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` to inject some values into an sql. I am having performance issues when I inject two `java.sql.Timestamp` values into the sql who's oracle column is of type `DATE` and executing.

It is extremely slow (approx. 4 minutes) but when I run it through sql developer it executes in less than a second since I have an index on that `DATE` column. Here is a snippet of my debug log:

```
select * from test_table.test_column where eventts >= :startDate and eventts <= :endDate and loginname= :loginname and channelind= :channelind
2014-04-21 15:02:50 48416 [http-8080-1] DEBUG org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate  - Executing prepared SQL query
2014-04-21 15:02:50 48417 [http-8080-1] DEBUG org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate  - Executing prepared SQL statement [select * from test_table.test_column where eventts >= ? and eventts <= ? and loginname= ? and channelind= ?]
2014-04-21 15:02:50 48417 [http-8080-1] DEBUG org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils  - Fetching JDBC Connection from DataSource
2014-04-21 15:02:50 48438 [http-8080-1] DEBUG org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils  - Setting SQL statement parameter value: column index 1, parameter value [2014-04-21 12:02:38.0], value class [java.sql.Timestamp], SQL type 93
2014-04-21 15:02:50 48439 [http-8080-1] DEBUG org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils  - Setting SQL statement parameter value: column index 2, parameter value [2014-04-22 00:00:00.0], value class [java.sql.Timestamp], SQL type 93
2014-04-21 15:02:50 48439 [http-8080-1] DEBUG org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils  - Setting SQL statement parameter value: column index 3, parameter value [MY_LOGIN], value class [java.lang.String], SQL type unknown
2014-04-21 15:02:50 48439 [http-8080-1] DEBUG org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils  - Setting SQL statement parameter value: column index 4, parameter value [WEB], value class [java.lang.String], SQL type unknown
```

What am I missing here? Is Oracle casting the values to a `TIMESTAMP` resulting in losing the index I have on the "eventts" `DATE` column?

Answer (score 0):

I think your guess is right.
When you have

```
select something from some_table where column1 = :val1
```

and va1 is not of the same type as column1, Oracle will do:

```
select something from some_table where to_val1type(column1) = :val1
```

Function to_val1type doesn't exists, it will decided by context (TO_DATE, TO_NUMBER, etc..)

either make your parameter of the same type, or use TO_XXX fuctnion yourself.